# Command to resolve domain name giving only IP address/in-addr.arpa

Tags: dns

I currently this to return the IP address of a host or return the in-addr.arpa record:

```
host $1 |
  perl -pe 's/.* mail is .*//; s/\n//;s/.* has address //;s/.* domain name pointer //;s/.* not found: .*/'$1'/g';
```

Is there a more authorized tool that gives only the IP address/in-addr.arpa and no other output?

Comment: host -t PTR 1.1.1.1 | awk ' { print $1 } '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get domain name from IP

`dig -x IP`

To get only short answer

`dig -x IP +short`

package with the binary may differ based on your distribution / os

- **dnsutils** on ubuntu,debian
- **bind-utils** on centos,fedora,etc

Comment: This works: `dig -x $input +short; dig $input +short`. Thanks